# convert real number to integer, What's the principle?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    float a;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("%f\n", (int)((a + 1) / 2) * a);
    printf("%d\n", (int)((a + 1) / 2) * a);
    return 0;
}
```

if I typed `4`, output is `8.0000`
I thought it should be `10.0000` because that code is `1+2+~+n`

I don't know the reason.

and second output is `0`
I thought it should be `10`

why this happen?

Comment: the principle is use %d to print int and %f to print float. When you print a float with %d it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Rule of thumb: never mix fixed point integers with floating point numbers in the same expression. Note that a constant  `1` has type `int` and a constant `1.0f` has type `float`. If you wish to convert from float to integer by truncation, then use explicit casts such as `my_int = (int)my_float;`. And finally, there are very few cases in C programming where you should actually use the `float` type. Beginners should always use `double` everywhere. The _only_ valid use-case for `float` is when you have a single-precision FPU and using `double` would mean software lib floating point calculations.

Comment: Most of the time, if you pass a value of one type to a function and it expects another, an automatic conversion happens.  For example, if you call `sqrt(144)`,  that works, because even though `144` is an `int`, the compiler knows from a proper function prototype that `sqrt` expects a `double`, and so performs a conversion automatically.

Comment: But `printf` is different.  `printf` accepts a variable number of arguments, so the compiler is not allowed (by the rules of the language) to perform that sort of automatic conversion.  So if you pass a floating-point number, but `%d` expects an `int`, no conversion is performed, and you get a meaningless answer.

Comment: Now, with all that said, a good compiler will peek at a `printf` format string, and check if you're passing things correctly, and warn you if you don't.  Did your compiler not give you a warning like "`format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'float'`"?  Mine did.  If your compiler didn't, you might want to figure out how to increase its warning level, or get a better compiler.

Comment: 이지민, save time.  Enable all compiler warnings to quickly see trouble with `float a; printf("%d\n", (int)((a + 1) / 2) * a);`.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%f\n", (int)((a + 1) / 2) * a);` is evaluated:

1. Since `a` has type `float` and value 4, `a+1` has type `float` and value 5.
2. Since `(a+1)` has type `float` and value 5, `(a+1) / 2` has type `float` and value 2½.
3. Since `(a + 1) / 2` has type `float` and value 2½, `((a + 1) / 2)` has type `float` and value 2½.
4. Since `((a + 1) / 2)` has type `float` and value 2½, `(int) ((a + 1) / 2)` has type `int` and value 2.
5. Since `(int) ((a + 1) / 2)` has type `int` and value 2 and `a` has type `float` and value 4, `(int)((a + 1) / 2) * a` has type `float` and value 8.
6. `printf("%f\n",…_);` with an argument of type `float` and value 8 converts 8 to “8.000000” and prints it. (The `float` argument is automatically promoted to `double` in this call.)

In `printf("%d\n", (int)((a + 1) / 2) * a);`, the argument again has type `float` and value 8. The behavior of passing an argument of type `float` for a conversion `%d` is not defined by the C standard. You need to match the argument type to the conversion specification.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
(int)((4.0f + 1) / 2) * 4.0f
```

evaluates to `8.0f` because the typecast to `int` has higher precedence than multiplication.  Thus, the above expression is equivalent to

```
((int)((4.0f + 1) / 2)) * 4.0f
```

You can imagine that being evaluated as

1. `4.0f + 1`  -->  `5.0f`
2. `5.0f / 2`  -->  `2.5f`
3. `(int) 2.5f`  -->  `2`
4. `2 * 4.0f`  -->  `8.0f`

And with respect to your first `printf`, it's *good* that precedence works that way, for the argument corresponding to a `%f` directive in a `printf` format must have type `double`.  The default argument promotions apply here, converting `float` to the needed `double`, but they would not apply to an `int`.

> and second output is 0 I thought it should be 10 why this happen?

I get a different output (neither 8 nor 10) from the second `printf`. And that's not surprising, because the `%d` format directive there requires the corresponding argument to have type `int`, whereas it actually has type `double`, as discussed above.  Undefined behavior results.

Always remember that `printf` and `scanf` formatting directives convey not only the wanted output format, but **even more** the expected type of the corresponding argument.  If you do not provide a corresponding argument of the correct type then all bets are off.